# How to remove insignificant decimal point in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

I'm trying to format a number in Google Spreadsheets. I want it to show the thousands comma, then a period `.`, followed by mostly 3 digits, only when necessary.

For example:

- `1,234.56789 => 1,234.568`
- `1,234.5     => 1,234.5`
- `1,234       => 1,234`
- `1,234.00    => 1,234`

I tried `#,#.#`, but then the period shows up always. `#,#.0` doesn't omit the decimal point when its value is zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

closest you can get is to use 1+ column

- go to **<kbd>123</kbd>** or **Format**
- select **Numbers**
- select **More formats**
- select **Custom number format...**
- type: **#,###.###**
- and corect it with: **`=IF(RIGHT(A2;1)=".";SUBSTITUTE(A2;".";"");A2)`**

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ep0EexMbLELHlqv8FnMWQWxCqsqW7ZMg9z50X0UUQCw/edit#gid=0)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there a way to correct the dot without a formula?

Comment: @Shimmy not rly, because it would then violate your last rule "followed by mostly 3 digits, only when necessary"

Comment: wtf this is awful. Is there a way to do that (without the last 3 digit rule asked by OP)

Comment: But this converts the number to a string, my format was `[$₹][>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹][>99999]##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹]##,##0.####` even by using value function I am not able to convert it to number format please help!

Comment: @AashitGarodia see perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773824/5632629

Comment: @user0 are you suggesting to use regex & Index?

Answer (score 2):

I know this won't resolve anything for most people, but for me the answer was to format the number as text in Excel before I copied it into Google sheets. Again, probably not useful, but for those of us who got it into Google this way, it might be helpful.